# npm install and codepush: The uploaded package was not released because it is identical to the contents of the specified deployment's current release

Tags: react-native, code-push

when i update a package with npm install only, codepush fails with message:

The uploaded package was not released because it is identical to the contents of the specified deployment's current release.

Is there a way to upload update even when there is only one package updated, right now users have to install new apk everytime package version changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a lot of information in this question, but this error is from the appcenter-cli, which produces this error if the target contents are the same as the source, indicating that it did not create a new codepush release.

This situation will happen all the time in a typical project. If this error is stopping your CI pipeline from completing, you can use the `--disable-duplicate-release-error` parameter, which simply reports a warning instead of an error.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/cli#no-duplicate-release-error-parameter for more details.

Comment: It converted Error to Warning! but not pushing code for me!

Answer (score -1):

I just did logout and login again! it worked